# Why my reimplementation of QCheckBox.hitButton works only for a small area of the check indicator?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'm trying to reimplement the [hitButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#hitButton) method of a QCheckBox, so that only the actual checkbox (i.e. not the label) is clickable. I'm not versed in C++, but looking at the [source for QCheckBox](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qcheckbox.cpp.html#_ZNK9QCheckBox9hitButtonERK6QPoint), I tried to reimplement the existing code in python to see if I could then get it to work how I wanted.

My thought was that I would only have to change `SE_CheckBoxClickRect` to `SE_CheckBoxIndicator`. The below only seems to work in a very small area of the checkmark box, and nowhere else:

```
class ClickCheckBox(QCheckBox):
    """subclass to reimplement hitButton"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ClickCheckBox, self).__init__(*args)

    def hitButton(self, QPoint):
        style = QStyle.SE_CheckBoxClickRect
        opt = QStyleOptionButton()

        return QApplication.style().subElementRect(style, opt, self).contains(QPoint)
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimplementing `QCheckBox.hitButton` and replacing `SE_CheckBoxClickRect` with `SE_CheckBoxIndicator` is indeed the right approach to make only the check indicator clickable.

I have tested it in C++ and it works as expected:

```
bool CheckBox::hitButton(const QPoint &pos) const
{
    QStyleOptionButton opt;
    initStyleOption(&opt);

    return style()->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_CheckBoxIndicator, &opt, this).contains(pos);
}
```

Now, try to exactly translate that to Python, including the call to `initStyleOption` you are missing:

```
def hitButton(self, pos):
    opt = QStyleOptionButton()
    self.initStyleOption(opt)

    return self.style().subElementRect(QStyle.SE_CheckBoxIndicator, opt, self).contains(pos)
```

Comment: @AlexanderTomlinson, you are very welcome! I would appreciate it, if you also consider upvoting the answer, once the system lets you do that.